# Extending a narrow high kitchen table with lateral side-wings

Tags: wood, kitchens, hinges, table

We have a narrow raised kitchen table (with bar stools):
[image]
[image]

I would like to build a simple extension for it so that more people fit around the table. Something like [this](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/65/7f/d3/657fd39fb83167b214d1fcd4d0c7afee.jpg) (or [this](http://etool.me/wp-content/uploads//2018/06/table-leaf-pedestal-drop-leaf-table-table-leaf-aligners-home-depot-table-leaf-extension-hardware.jpg)) would be ideal, but since I have limited skills (and time), I just tried to improvise something simple.

What I had in mind was to buy two appropriately-sized pieces of wood (about half the current length of the table) and affix them as "side-wings", one on each lateral side towards the leg-end, using hinges. These extensions would then hang vertically in the regular configuration when the base table suffices; and be raised horizontally when the table needs to be extended. Since the addition would be symmetric, I reckoned that the central support foot (pictured) would still be enough, as long as each of the wings has its own support from underneath.

The plan is simple enough, but aside from doing the measurements and buying the two pieces of wood (easy), I have no idea how to start:
- how do I choose the type of hinge, and how do I mount it on each piece of wood, as well as on the existing table!
- what kind of support would each wing need to stay upright, that is itself foldable when the wing is folded downwards?

I am also open to other suggestions for how to extend this table side-ways, in case the hinged&supported lateral wings solution does not seem optimal. I am grateful in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Are you sure you'll be happy with the wings dangling in your knee space most of the time?

Comment: Good point - I thought I'd size/cut the wings just large enough to leave sufficient knee space when dangling down; this should still mean they are large enough to make for a decent extension of space

Answer (score 2):

I'd build your wings and attach slide-in bars, along the lines of what's shown here. You could use hoop brackets instead of the horizontal bar running between the legs in this example, or go ahead and mount a 1x3 maple or birch board permanently under your table on each side. You could wrap it around three sides so it appears more like a conventional skirt.

[image]

<sub>[image source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjj5ruC77DeAhXK7oMKHYPEBkUQjhx6BAgBEAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fknocker.me%2Fluxury_dining-table-with-extension%2Fluxury_dining-table-with-extension-the-dee-kitchen-real-oak-furniture-co&psig=AOvVaw0iVeYUS-GacZDsFtfzyRpa&ust=1541081632179035)</sub>

This gives you good support, plus you can remove and stow the wings where they won't impeded table use when not deployed.

Regarding stability, table symmetry is just part of the equation. Table contents and the upper body weight of those resting elbows on the table are probably more significant. However, as long as your table is well attached to the wall at the far end it should remain stable.